# UI not updating in Android using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-asynctask, android-button

I've searched the internet far and wide about getting the UI to update in real-time in Android to no avail. I implemented an AysncTask class as most of the other posts suggested, but it's still not updating my UI in real-time like I want. It only updates after the program is done running. I've even been getting the "Skipped n frames. The application may be doing too much work in its main thread." error, which I don't understand because I'm trying to do these updates in the UI thread. About 5 seconds into running my program the screen turns black and stays like that until its done finishing. Any help would be much appreciated as I've been pulling my hair out on this one for awhile Here's my code.

EDIT: Solved. Removed the Thread.sleep(n) from my UI thread and added it to my AsyncTask. Thanks everyone!

Main class:

```
public class Home extends Activity {
// Declare objects
Button turingB, socratesB, voltaireB, descartesB, platoB;
int[] eating, thinking, hungry;
Philosopher socrates, turing, voltaire, descartes, plato;
Philosopher[] philosophers;
Chopstick[] chopsticks;
TextView info;
String value;
Context context;
int toastLength;
boolean turingHungry, socratesHungry, voltaireHungry, descartesHungry, platoHungry;
String running;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // Instantiate objects (keep track of each button individually
    context = getApplicationContext();
    toastLength = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    info.setText("Click Start to begin!");
    socratesB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    descartesB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    platoB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    voltaireB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    turingB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    running = "false";

    // Set all philosophers to thinking (blue)
    //      socratesB.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    //      descartesB.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    //      platoB.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    //      voltaireB.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    //      turingB.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    turingHungry = false;
    socratesHungry = false;
    voltaireHungry = false;
    descartesHungry = false;
    platoHungry = false;

    //Button platoTempButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    // Listen for buttons
    OnClickListener pBtn = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            platoHungry = true;
        }
    };
    //platoTempButton.setOnClickListener(pBtn);

    OnClickListener tBtn = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            turingHungry = true;
        }
    };
    OnClickListener sBtn = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            socratesHungry = true;
        }
    };
    OnClickListener vBtn = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            voltaireHungry = true;
        }
    };
    OnClickListener dBtn = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            descartesHungry = true;
        }
    };
    platoB.setOnClickListener(pBtn);
    turingB.setOnClickListener(tBtn);
    socratesB.setOnClickListener(sBtn);
    voltaireB.setOnClickListener(vBtn);
    descartesB.setOnClickListener(dBtn);

    // Set arrays to count time spent eating, thinking, hungry
    eating = new int[5];
    thinking = new int[5];
    hungry = new int[5];

    // Create the chopsticks
    chopsticks = new Chopstick[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    {
        chopsticks[i] = new Chopstick(i);
    }
    for (Chopstick chop: chopsticks)
    {
        chop.available = true;
    }

    // Create the philosophers
    philosophers = new Philosopher[5];
    philosophers[0] = new Philosopher(0, chopsticks[0], chopsticks[1], "Plato", platoB);
    philosophers[1] = new Philosopher(1, chopsticks[1], chopsticks[2], "Turing", turingB);
    philosophers[2] = new Philosopher(2, chopsticks[2], chopsticks[3], "Socrates", socratesB);
    philosophers[3] = new Philosopher(3, chopsticks[3], chopsticks[4], "Voltaire", voltaireB);
    philosophers[4] = new Philosopher(4, chopsticks[4], chopsticks[0], "Descartes", descartesB);    

    // Get sim time from user
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Simulation Time");
    alert.setMessage("Please length of time for the simulation to run (in seconds)");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            value = String.valueOf(input.getText());
        }
    });
    alert.show();

    // Get info
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        running = extras.getString("runApp");
        value = extras.getString("numToRun");
    }
    // Run app
    if (running.equals("true"))
    {
        System.out.println("RUNNING!!!");
        run(value);
    }
}

public void run(String length)
{
    int num = Integer.parseInt(length);
    // Run num times
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        try {
            // Pass current index, and data arrays to step method
            step(i, eating, thinking, hungry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Print out some data
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("Philosopher " + j + " ate: " + eating[j]);
        System.out.println("Philosopher " + j + " thought: " + thinking[j]);
        System.out.println("Philosopher " + j + " was hungry: " + hungry[j]);
    }
    running = "false";
}

// Run simulation n times (n specified by the user) 
public void startSim(View v)
{
    Intent my_intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    my_intent.putExtra("runApp", "true");
    my_intent.putExtra("numToRun", value);
    startActivity(my_intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}
// Reset simulation
public void reset(View v)
{
    Intent my_intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    startActivity(my_intent);
}

// Return hunger status of philosopher
public boolean isHungry(String name) {
    if (name.equals("Voltaire"))
        return voltaireHungry;
    else if (name.equals("Socrates"))
        return socratesHungry;
    else if (name.equals("Plato"))
        return platoHungry;
    else if (name.equals("Turing"))
        return turingHungry;
    else if (name.equals("Descartes"))
        return descartesHungry;
    else
        return false;
}

// Step method for simulation
// Takes the current index and each of the data arrays
public void step(int i, int[] eating, int[] thinking, int[] hungry) throws InterruptedException
{
    // Make random number
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int num = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

    // Randomly set a philosopher isFull to false (hungry) (10% chance for each to become hungry if not specified by the user)
    if (isHungry(philosophers[0].name))
        philosophers[0].isFull = false;
    if (num == 1 || isHungry(philosophers[1].name))
        philosophers[1].isFull = false;
    if (num == 2 || isHungry(philosophers[2].name))
        philosophers[2].isFull = false;
    if (num == 3 || isHungry(philosophers[3].name))
        philosophers[3].isFull = false;
    if (num == 4 || isHungry(philosophers[4].name))
        philosophers[4].isFull = false;


    // For each philosopher
    for (Philosopher phil: philosophers)
    {
        // Print current info
        System.out.println("PHIL: " + phil.name + " NUM: " + num + " RIGHT: " + phil.rightChopstick.available + " LEFT: " + phil.leftChopstick.available);
        // Temp id var
        int tempId = phil.id;

        // If philosopher is hungry, try to eat
        if (phil.isFull == false)
        {
            // Try to eat only if both chopsticks are available
            if (phil.rightChopstick.pickUp(phil.name) && phil.leftChopstick.pickUp(phil.name))
            {
                // Change button color
                new Background(phil.button).execute((long) 1);
                //Toast.makeText(context, phil.name + " is eating.", toastLength).show();
                // Increment time spent eating
                eating[tempId]++;                           
            }
            // Check to see if the philosopher is already eating (has both chopsticks)
            else if (phil.rightChopstick.who.equals(phil.name) && phil.leftChopstick.who.equals(phil.name))
            {
                //Toast.makeText(context, phil.name + " is eating.", toastLength).show();
                new Background(phil.button).execute((long) 1);
                // Increment eating
                eating[tempId]++;
                // 30% chance to stop eating
                if (num >= 5 && num <=7)
                {
                    // Put down chopsticks
                    phil.rightChopstick.putDown();
                    phil.leftChopstick.putDown();
                    // Stop eating
                    phil.isFull = true;
                }
            }
            // Hungry
            else
            {
                // Change button color
                new Background(phil.button).execute((long) 3);
                //Toast.makeText(context, phil.name + " is hungry.", toastLength).show();

                // Increment time spent hungry
                hungry[tempId]++;                       
            }
        }               
        // Thinking
        else
        {
            new Background(phil.button).execute((long) 2);
            //Toast.makeText(context, phil.name + " is thinking.", toastLength).show();
            // Increment time spent thinking
            thinking[tempId]++;
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }           
    // Make each step count as 1 second (1000 miliseconds)
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

}

Background class (AsyncTask):

```
public class Background extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, Void> 
{
// Variables
String color;
Button button;

public Background(Button button)
{
    this.button = button;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Long... params) {    
    // Get which color the button needs to be
    try
    {
        // Change the color based on the value passed in
        if (params[0] == 3)
        {
            color = "RED";
        }
        else if (params[0] == 2)
        {
            color = "BLUE";
        }
        else if (params[0] == 1)
        {
            color = "GREEN";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // Set button to that color
    System.out.println("Updating color in real time...");
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one problem

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

and here is another

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

these are both making the `UI` sleep for a total of 6 seconds. You *almost* never want to call `sleep()` on the `UI Thread`. You can do this in `doInBackground()` or anywhere else that runs on a background `Thread`.

**Edit**

You don't set your `Listeners`. For example:

```
platoB.setOnClickListener(new pBtn());
```

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you! One other question if you have time. For some reason, my buttons aren't clickable when the application is running, but are beforehand. Any idea why?

Comment: You will need to be a little more clear. They *can't* be clickable when your app isn't running because there wouldn't be anything to click

Comment: Well in my onClickListener for each button I added a simple print statement when it's clicked. When I click the button the statement doesn't print and the variable I'm trying to change by clicking the button doesn't update either.

Comment: I will look at that as that is explainable but please explain, "but are beforehand." referring to your buttons being clickable

Comment: One more question. How can I get the main thread to sleep without calling Thread.sleep(n)? I want each step through my run method to be one second long to give the user time to click the button.

Comment: You don't want the user to wait for anything. They will hate you for it. If you do, `Thread.sleep(1000);` will do it but it usually isn't a good idea

Comment: But if I don't implement some sort of delay the program finishes before they even have a chance to click a button to make a philosopher hungry.

Comment: I would need more information on what you are trying to do before I could suggest a good practice or implementation

Comment: In my run method, I call step n times. Step goes through each of the philosophers and changes the button color based on certain conditions. Each time I call step in my run method I want to represent one second. That's why I was putting in a delay in the first place. Basically I want my program to run for n seconds. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You want to look at [postDelayed](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fos%2FHandler.html&ei=96gjU-bJGMH6qAG484GoBw&usg=AFQjCNH69MZ5ecq3l7PexAitL-u1vPr27g&sig2=wTqwm2DdTSRPa7GTnS67Rw&bvm=bv.62922401,d.aWM)

Answer (score 0):

Progress can be set with publishProgress in your asynctask, you get a call to onProgressUpdate in the UI thread.

Comment: So I just need to add publishProgress(); at the bottom of my doInBackground()?